# SQL change data type from INT to TEXT side effects?

Tags: mysql, sql

I been working with a database where I gave unique numeric ID,
now I want to give string instead, but keep the old records good and runing.
I will use the next SQL script

```
ALTER TABLE bowow_new.bowow_result
MODIFY autoID TEXT;
```

would I be able to use my DB as usual, or would it cause major problems?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  It doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: Company is merging, and now this is the standard.

Comment: You may lose some functionality, performance and/or flexibility on features that are number-biased, like table partitioning or range searches (BETWEEN).  Just make sure that all the corresponding columns have the same data types so that you do actual string-string comparisons, and you should be OK.

Comment: Thank you Ravioli.